# Print file directories along with storage space and userid in linux

Tags: linux, awk, directory

I am trying to print out the details of the user with the total storage consumption group by the directory. Below is the code snippet i have written so far.

```
find $1 -atime +$2 -size +$3M -type f -exec ls -lu --block-size=MB \
{} \; | awk '{print $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9}' | awk '
{ a[$1] += $3 }
END {
for (i in a) {
  printf "%-15s\t%s\n", i, a[i];
}
}'
```

Above code print the userid and the total storage consumption.

Below is the sample ouput of above code

```
user1     500MB
```

But I want to print the directory info too along with the storage consumption of particular directory

So lets take the input coming as

```
user1    100 MB   /dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/file1
user1    100 MB   /dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/file2
user1    150 MB   /dir1/dir2/dir3/dir5/file1
user1    150 MB   /dir1/dir2/dir3/dir5/file2
```

The output I am trying to display is

```
user1         200 MB  /dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4
user1         300 MB  /dir1/dir2/dir3/dir5
```

Can someone help me on how to implement this?

Comment: You might want to use [du(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/du.1.html). Perhaps you want [disk quota](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_quota)s..., e.g. [repquota(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/repquota.8.html)

Answer (score 0):

Optimized **`find`** + **`numfmt`** solution:

```
find $1 -atime +$2 -size +$3M -type f \
-printf "%-15u\t%kK\t%p\n" | numfmt --field=2 --from=iec --to=iec -d$'\t'
```

Comment: Seems like numfmt is not support in my current linux version. Do we have have any other workaround?

Comment: @Ankug, here you are: `find $1 -atime +$2 -size +$3M -type f \
-printf "%-15u\t%kK\t%p\n" | awk -v OFS='\t' '{ $2=sprintf("%.1fM", $2/1024) }1'`